# How to enforce input text to take 100% width of its parent

Tags: html, css

How to enforce `input text` to take 100% width of its parent (`div class="input-wrapper"`), which is responsive? `Width:inherit` make it wide for whole `viewport` and `width:auto` doesn't work as well, because it makes input default `size="20"`. I want to have two containers with `width` in `px` and central container with input responsive. Take a look at my simple plunker.

HTML:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="square" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  width: auto;
}

.one {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.input-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wtaXo3N4j4hKyeWI0l5i?p=preview

Comment: No - width: inherit is computing for 100% and - as I mentioned - it make component wide for whole viewport

Comment: *How to enforce input text to take 100% width of its parent*: --- by making its parent fixed width.

Comment: But I want to leave it responsive.

Comment: By fixed width I mean "some width" not "auto". Width can be in percent for it to be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.input-wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy and quick answer?
Use "min-width" instead of "width".

Just now I was confronting with the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Example of code in my case:

```
<input type="text" name="CommentText" placeholder="Write comment here..."
               style="min-width:100%; height:100px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also add

```
.input-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
input {
    width:100%;
}
```

100 % width takes from first non-static parent. In your example - it is `body`.

**UPD**

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    outline:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing:none;
}

.input-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-right:150px;
}
```

Comment: It makes two side containers hidden.

Comment: @magos See the update, it works for me, like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="two">
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="square" style="width:98%"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Styles go here */

input {
  width: auto;
}

.one {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 34%;
  float: left;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 60px;
  width: 33%;
  float: right;
}

.input-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is I don't want to have two side containers 33%. They have to have width in px.

Answer (score 0):

you should use flex:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="two">
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="square" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
}

input {
  width: auto;
}

.one {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.three {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 60px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.input-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

you can also play with the orientation. I hope it helps